# index_merge full table scan - 2 seconds mysql select

Tags: mysql

I have this select:

```
  SELECT MAX(id) FROM chat
  WHERE (`to` = 1 and `del_to_status` = '0') or (`from` = 1 and `del_from_status` = '0')
  GROUP BY CASE WHEN 1 = `to` THEN `from` ELSE `to` END
```

chat:

```
`chat` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `from` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `to` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `del_from_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `del_to_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `from` (`from`),
  KEY `to` (`to`),
);
```

The problem is it is using full table scan:

[image]

it is taking a lot of time. any ideas to get faster results?

Comment: We need some explanation about what you are trying to achive in the query

Comment: @omriman12 I'm using it inside a `select c.to, c.from from chat c where c.id IN(` to group messages into conversations ordering by last messages.

Comment: What is `del_from_status` and `del_to_status` ? also aren't you missing a `date` column?

Comment: @omriman12 if an user deleted the grouped message, I'll set del to 1, but only for this user, the other part of the conversation can see the message. so if from deleted, del_from = 1, if to deleted it = del_to = 1. but with or without this part the result will be the same on explain.

Comment: 1 more question, still not clear, is this a chat between multiple users? isn't there suppose to be a `chat_id` column? or this all part of 1 chat? and you want to get the last message which is not deleted for each conversation in the chat grouping by the user?

Comment: @omriman12 it is a chat table, the system has many users (user 1 to 10000) and they can send messages to each other. But one user will have a conversation to another user only (1 - 2) or (2 - 3)... . user a talk to user b. user a talk to user c. user c talk to user a... I have an id column, autoincrement. Your last question answer is yes, perfect.

Comment: Oh, should I use a conversation_id? to select by conversation?

Comment: Yea, if you use `conversation_id` thats the  solution, I also added a query fitting to your schema. Also I advice you to add a `date` column, and the `message`  move to another table named `messages`, and only keep the `message-id` in the `chat` table

Answer (score 1):

What do you think about this solution:

```
select grouped_by_to.user, greatest(grouped_by_to.id, grouped_by_from.id ) from 
(
    select c1.to as user, max(id) as id from chat c1
    group by c1.to 
) grouped_by_to

join
(
    select c1.from as user, max(id) as id from chat c1
    group by c1.from
) grouped_by_from on grouped_by_from.user = grouped_by_to.user
```

Note that i ignored the `del_to_status` columns, you can add them easily.

But actually I think your whole db schema is wrong, I think you need something more like :

```
`messages` (
  `message_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `message_date` timestamp NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`message_id`),
);

`conversatinos` (
  `conversation_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `message_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`conversation_id`),
);

`users` (
  `user_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_name` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
);
```

AND maybe if you need:

```
`chat` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `message_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
);
```

Comment: thank you very much, your select took about 1 second, better then mine, but I think I will try a new schema for this.

Comment: @Rick Joe yes the schema you posted is very wrong my friend, you must read about `database normalization` and try to split the tables as much as needed. please accept the answer if it helper you :]